# How to fix moving several items in uicollectionview sometimes crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with several sections. The collection view allows a user to move several items from one section to another. The way it works is that the user selects the items, taps "move" and selects the new section.

The function below does the move. It works just fine when there is only one item selected, and it sometimes works when there are several items selected. However, every now and then it crashes when moving several items.  The crash happens in the pictureforItemAtIndexPath function and the reason is that my dataArray is out of range (dataArray being the array providing the data to the collection view).

I am not sure what could be wrong and why it sometimes works.

```
func movePictures(newCategory: String) {
    if let selected = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems {

        for indexPath in selected {
            print("IndexPath is: \(indexPath)")
            let currentPicture = dataSource.pictureForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
            currentPicture.pictureCategory = newCategory

            let newSectionNumber = dataSource.getSectionNumber(sectionName: newCategory)
            let newIndexPath = dataSource.getNewIndexPath(sectionNumber: newSectionNumber)

            dataSource.moveItemAtIndexPath(from: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
            collectionView.moveItem(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)

        }


        self.deselectAllItems()


    }
}

func pictureForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Picture {

    return dataArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sort the selected items in decreasing `item` order. If you move a lower item before moving a higher item, the source array size will decrease, leading to a potential bounds exception.

```
if let selected = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems {

    let sortedSelected = selected.sorted {
        return $0.item > $1.item
    }

    for indexPath in sortedSelected {
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, naturally. Thank you so much. This worked. I will accept your answer but will also look into performBatchUpdates as suggested by FJ.

Answer (score 0):

To move, insert or delete multiple items while animating the changes, you need to use `performBatchUpdates` on your collection view. Read about it in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates).

This ensures that your final state can be reconciled with your `UICollectionViewDataSource`. Otherwise, it is very hard to represent the intermediary states (where parts of your collection view cells have changed but not all changes are committed) with your `UICollectionViewDataSource`.